# MySQL Regex Search and replace

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I would like to remove height property from all my images in my database. Their markup is as follows:

```
<img src="path/img.jpg" width="x" height="y" />
```

I was going to do something like this:

```
UPDATE jos_content SET introtext = REPLACE(introtext, 'height=".*"', '');
```

But I don't know how to use regular expressions in MySQL query. I did find out they exist, I just don't se how I can use them in this context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Source**](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/)

Try Below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And Run your Update query as

```
UPDATE jos_content SET introtext = regex_replace('height=".*"', 'height=""',introtext);
```

Comment: why `REPLACE(` and not `regex_replace(` ?

Comment: @Sharky I have made change...

Comment: It worked! But what a behemoth of a function. I thought using regex in mysql was as easy as 123.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how this works. The way I'm reading it, this loops through one character at a time and checks the regex against each individual character. So it checks to see if the letter 'h' matches the regex of `height=".*"`, which of course it doesn't - so how could this work? I must be missing something.

Comment: this not work exactly as regex replace because the amount of characters matching can be different there is no logic doing that in this code. when i tested i specifically added ^ to match only beginning of the string but it still replace the numbers at the end too.