# Mysql Regex Search and Replace not updating records

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MYSQL database that needs some data removed from a field.

My current data is like this..

```
gttp://www.somesite.com?ref=1234567
gttp//notquitealink.com/ref.php?r=myreferral
```

I am trying to remove the gttp://www.somesite.com?ref=  to leave only the last part after the =

so I want the data to look like this

```
1234567
myreferral
```

I found this code from a previous question.    [MySQL Regex Search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421840/mysql-regex-search-and-replace?rq=1)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I ran it and it created a function that I could query on.

When I run this query....

```
UPDATE `tb_te_builder_user` SET tebu_refID = regex_replace('gttp(.*)=', '',tebu_refID);
```

I get 0 rows affected. (Query took 10.9480 sec)

But when I try to do a select

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_te_builder_user` WHERE tebu_refID REGEXP 'gttp(.*)='
```

I get well over 7,000 records returned.

I am not quite sure what to make of it...  I think I am missing something very simple here.

I was also looking at this solution  https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme  but I don't have rights to use the make command on my server. So I am left with trying to figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Buster this selects only 5 records... out of 7000 all of them end with w

Comment: Sorry I cant test right now, but i will look into it tomorrow

Comment: SELECT * FROM `tb_te_builder_user` WHERE tebu_refID REGEXP '.*\=(.+)'

Answer (score 0):

That function only works for a single character pattern. This limitation is mentioned at the [source site](https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/).

For a string pattern you may use a user defined function, eg. [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp), see [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). However, to install a user defined function you need to compile it and add it to the MySQL installation.

MariaDB, a MySQL drop-in replacement, has a [builtin function `regex_replace`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/string-functions/regular-expressions-functions/regexp_replace/) fully supporting string patterns.

If you cannot do any of these you may try an external solution, eg. using PHP and PHP's [`preg_replace`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

Comment: I guess I missed that it's a simple char pattern.  Now mysql-udf-regexp is this something I have to install?  I don't have access to make on my server.  MariaDB is out of the question also.. The only access I have to Mysql is PHPMyadmin. Unless I am missing something ?