# 'Advanced' Mysql query using REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I have two relational tables, `t1` has the column `call_number` and `t2` has `phone_number`.

Example tables:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | call_number |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | 36202665476 |
+----+-------------+

+----+-----------------+
| id |   phone_number  |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | +36 20 266-5476 |
+----+-----------------+
```

I have to write a query which give back these two "matching" rows, using regexp, without any modification on the database.

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* 
FROM t1,t2 
WHERE 
t1.call_number REGEXP concat( t2.phone_number, '[^0-9]')
```

So in the query I have to remove unnecessary characters (from `t2.phone_number`) THEN compare that "trimmed" column with `t1.call_number` to find a match.

Any advice comes in handy.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Regex Search and replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421840/mysql-regex-search-and-replace)

Comment: @Stephan This is nothing like that. He's not trying to replace the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar He's trying to remove any non digit.

Comment: He's using the regexp to relate the two tables.

Comment: @Barmar His intent is clear: remove any character that is not a digit (ie replace any character that is not a digit with the empty char) then compare the resulting string with the values in `t1`.

Comment: oh, you think that's what he meant by `concat(t2.phone_number, '[^0-9]')`. You could be right, I never thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just replace the surplus characters in the join condition like this:

```
select *
from t1 
join t2 
  on t1.call_number = replace(replace(replace(t2.phone_number, ' ',''), '-',''),'+','')
```

Of course you would have to know in advance and account for all the characters that should be removed.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afe45/6)

Sample result showing the match:

```
| id | call_number | id |    phone_number |
|----|-------------|----|-----------------|
|  1 | 36202665476 |  1 | +36 20 266-5476 |
```

Comment: Thank you all answers, I just wanted to filter out  unnecessary characters with regexp, but that did the job:
on t1.call_number = replace(replace(replace(t2.phone_number, ' ',''), '-',''),'+','') 
So Regexp no needed

Answer (score 1):

Then execute this query to fetch the numbers that have matching values:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `t1`,`t2`
WHERE t1.`call_number` REGEXP REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t2.`phone_number`, ' ', ''),'-', ''),'+', '');
```

Comment: He said **without any modification of the database**.

Comment: is the id not the relation between the tables ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen The relation between the tables is the phone numbers.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited the answer to ensure the database is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

Call `REPLACE` in the argument to `CONCAT` to remove the special characters.

```
WHERE t1.call_number REGEXP CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t2.phone_number, ' ', ''),'-', ''),'+', ''), '[^0-9]')
```

Note that concatenating `[^0-9]` means it will only find a match where the matching number is followed by a non-numeric character. So it won't match the two example rows you showed, because there's nothing after the `call_number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE if your MySQL / MariaDB not to old

```
MariaDB > SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ab12cd','[^0-9]','') AS only_digits;
+-------------+
| only_digits |
+-------------+
| 12          |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```