# Extract a URL Valid or Invalid from a MYSQL data column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column within my MYSQL database `headline TEXT NOT NULL` 
I would like to go through this column for each of my records and extract the URL if it has one. The URL will be stored in another column `article_url VARCHAR (225) NULL`. If there is no URL then it would just put `NULL` in the column.

Lastly, I would like this to update each time a new record is inserted into the database. Below is what I have thus far.

UPDATE: here is an example of the headline column of my data
`Drastic decline in Social Sciences intake *: http:// bit.ly/2vXzPhQ pic.twitter.com/PAZvG3tX17` as you can see there is a URL in the data set however the URL is broken, all URLs are broken with a space between http:// and the rest of the URL. So I need to get a function in `PHP` that can find the Valid or Invalid URL when it gets the Invalid URL it will fix it.

this is what I have thus far.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$reg_exp = "/^(http(s?): \/\/)?(www\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?$/";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " headline: " . $row["headline"]. "<br>";
        if(preg_match($reg_exp, $row["headline"]) == TRUE)
        {
            echo "URL is valid format";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "URL is invalid format";
        }
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Need more information - when you say extract, from what - the column headline? What is stored in headline? Have you attempted this at all? If so post your code!

Comment: @Matt haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. The column has text within it like a tweet and sometimes a url.

Comment: So you are saying the headline is a html string so will contain html like <a href="url">Link</a> and you want to extract the url form this? Or it can be in multiple formats? Where does headline come from?

Comment: @Matt no am saying a headline is a tweet so its 140 characters that can possibly have a url within it and I would like to extract the URL from that body of text.

Comment: Okay.. sounds like you want to use regex one the string. Maybe try `preg_match_all('!https?://\S+!', $string, $matches);` let me know how you get on. If you need more info i'll put it in an answer

Comment: Matt answered the php-Way, This would take to retrieve all values in php, do the code and update back to the MySQL table.

Comment: @Matt going to update my question

Answer (score 0):

For a MySQL only solution you have four parts to parts solve:

1. one to run as update on existing data entries
2. one to run as [AFTER INSERT Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)
3. For both 1+2 you need the correct [REGEX-Syntax of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html). The php-regex might be a good starting point to do a `SELECT headline, Headline REGEXP '(insert your regex here)' FROM table;`. with that SELECT you can iterative check on your database, if your regex is correct.
4. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22421926/7564182) you find a version of regexp_replace, which you can add to your database. This can be used in the `UPDATE table SET artice_url = IF(...REGEXP...) regexp_replace(headline,...)` (the ... needs also to be filled correctly) as well as in the Trigger.